# C# entity framework MVC second run error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, localdb

I am creating db and initializing data with code below, if DB doesnt exist, it creates db and populate it, when I run application second time I get error

```
Cannot drop database "aspnet-app" because it is currently in use.
```

Application_start, with initializations

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Database.SetInitializer(new ComponentDbInitialize());
        ComputerContext context = new ComputerContext();
        context.Database.Initialize(true); //here it fails on second run
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

ComputerContext

```
 public ComputerContext():base("name=Default")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Motherboard> Motherboards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CPU> CPUs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Case> Cases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HDD> HDDs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RAM> RAMs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GPU> GPUs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PSU> PSUs { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize class

```
public class ComponentDbInitialize : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ComputerContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ComputerContext context)
    {
        GetCpu().ForEach(p => context.CPUs.Add(p));
        GetGpu().ForEach(p => context.GPUs.Add(p));
        GetCase().ForEach(p => context.Cases.Add(p));
        GetHdd().ForEach(p => context.HDDs.Add(p));
        GetMb().ForEach(p => context.Motherboards.Add(p));
        GetPsu().ForEach(p => context.PSUs.Add(p));
        GetRam().ForEach(p => context.RAMs.Add(p));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
private static List<CPU> GetCpu() .....
private static List<GPU> GetGpu().....
private static List<HDD> GetHdd()....
private static List<Case> GetCase()....
private static List<Motherboard> GetMb()....
private static List<PSU> GetPsu()....
private static List<RAM> GetRam()....
```

I get same error even with

```
context.Database.Initialize(false);
```

Thank you for any help/advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialiser is using the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` class which, as it suggests, drops that database every time the application is initialised.

Instead perhaps you could use `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` or `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`:

```
public class ComponentDbInitialize : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ComputerContext>
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, solved problem. In every tutorial I've been following they used this `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` Strategy, my bad. By the way, is this the correct way to create/manipulate DB as I do in my code ? And why does it fails when it should delete DB? Both of your strategies works like a charm. Thank you again.

Comment: This is a reasonable way to manipulate your databases. The reason for the fail was the a connection was open to the database already, possibly this is Visual Studio or your app itself.

Comment: I accepted your answer just had to wait some 10minutes cooldown, your answer came too fast ;) I just found out it has something to do with SSMS in visual studio and workaround is to set Pooling to false, but I rather solve problem then work it around. Thank you for your time.